# Android: Error:(464) Attribute "dividerPadding" has already been defined

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I try to debug my appliaction am getting an error

**Error:(464) Attribute "dividerPadding" has already been defined**

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple.jar')
compile 'com.lantouzi.wheelview:library:1.1.2'
compile project(path: ':pageStripLibrary')
}
```

I face this issue after adding "**pageStripLibrary**".
When I try to debug the appliaction

```
    <declare-styleable name="PagerSlidingTabStrip">
    <attr format="color" name="indicatorColor"/>
    <attr format="color" name="underlineColor"/>
    <attr format="color" name="dividerColor"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="indicatorHeight"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="underlineHeight"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="dividerPadding"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="tabPaddingLeftRight"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="scrollOffset"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="tabBackground"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="shouldExpand"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

this line of code is automaticaly generated in value.xml under 
**build > intermediate>res>merged>debug>values>values.xml**

Comment: Do you have id.xml file in res?

Comment: that comes under the path "Health\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values " the file is genrating when I try to debug. under the value folder, I have only value.xml no other files. @M D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please, try to remove or comment from your `attrs.xml` (the file is in `res/values/attrs.xml` in the project 'pageStripLibrary'):

```
    <attr format="dimension" name="dividerPadding"/>
```

because its already defined by `support:appcompat`